# Spring Cloud File System Backend placeholder does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use Spring Cloud Config Server File System Backend placeholder to access property files inside subdirectories. This is my directory structure:- `C://app-config/testDir1, C://app-config/testDir2`.
I am able to access property files inside app-config directory but unable to read the ones inside sub directories.

This is how my "application.properties" looks like-

```
server.port=8888

spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///C:\\app-config\\
```

"bootstrap.properties"

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.application.name=testDir1
spring.profiles.active=sit
```

I am using `spring.cloud.version` - `Greenwich.SR3`. By reading some similar posts in stackoverflow I understand that this issue occured in versions which were older than `Brixton.M5`. But my version is the latest, so wondering what might have gone wrong.

Please suggest.